# how to resolve conflicts between layouts

Tags: blocks, phtml

I have two conflicting modules,unbxed and criteo

app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\unbxd\search.xml:

section 1(unbxed module):

```
   <catalogsearch_result_index>
//somecode which is not important for us
   <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block name="unbxd.search" template="unbxd/search/result.phtml" after="-" type="core/template"/>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
```

the other module has the following:
section 2(criteo module):

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\zefir\trackers\criteo.xml
  <catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
      <block type="conversiontracking/criteo_search" name="criteo.search" template="zefir/conversiontracking/criteo/search.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </catalogsearch_result_index>
```

I am not sure what is the best way to resolve conflict, I need to have both phtml files being included on the result page.

P.S: if I remove section 2, the result.phtml shows up but if I don't I only see search.phtml from criteo, therefore section 2 is overwriting section 1 for some reason which I cannot figure it out and by the way one block type is `core/template` and the other one is comming from the module which is `conversiontracking/criteo_search`

here is unbxed config.xml as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Unbxd_Search>
            <version>1.0.22</version>
        </Unbxd_Search>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <unbxd_search>
                    <file>unbxd/search.xml</file>
                </unbxd_search>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <unbxd_search>
                <class>Unbxd_Search_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>unbxd_search_resource</resourceModel>
            </unbxd_search>
            <unbxd_search_resource>
                <class>Unbxd_Search_Model_Resource</class>
            </unbxd_search_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <unbxd_search>
                <class>Unbxd_Search_Helper</class>
            </unbxd_search>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
            <data>Unbxd_Search_Helper_Catalogsearch</data>
        </rewrite>
        </catalogsearch>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <unbxd_search>
                <class>Unbxd_Search_Block</class>
            </unbxd_search>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite><layer_view>Unbxd_Search_Block_Catalog_Layer_View</layer_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer>Unbxd_Search_Block_Catalogsearch_Layer</layer>
                    <autocomplete>Unbxd_Search_Block_Autocomplete</autocomplete>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
            <enterprise_search>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalogsearch_layer>Unbxd_Search_Block_Catalogsearch_Enterprise_Layer</catalogsearch_layer>
                </rewrite>
            </enterprise_search>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <unbxd_search_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Unbxd_Search</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </unbxd_search_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>

    //some code
</config>
```

I have done this:

```
  var_dump($this->getLayout()->getXmlString());
```

and here is the order the layout has it:

```
   <reference name="before_body_end">
      <block type="core/template" name="unbxd.search" template="unbxd/search/result.phtml"/>
   </reference>
   <reference name="before_body_end">
      <block type="conversiontracking/criteo_search" name="criteo.search" template="zefir/conversiontracking/criteo/search.phtml" />
   </reference>
```

I think because the criteo is loaded after the unbxed, it is just showing the criteo but not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Just curious, `<block name="unbxd.search"` is it right name? Can you add your `etc/config.xml` part as well.

Comment: for which one unbxed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have noticed that if any block which we added before body end having fatal error then it will stop further execution.So please review error log files and make sure there is no any error appear which are loaded before unbxd layout.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a conflict per say. Based on just the two layouts you've added, the two template should be added just fine, without problems. The hole pretext for Magento to allow any handle in any layout file is to allow for exactly what is happening in your case! It allows any module to add to anything on any page on the site - that's flexbility!!

try remove the after="-" from the unboxed search layout, the after="-" might be causing problems.

Comment: if I enable the module criteo,  the result.phtml is not there anymore

Comment: Just to try - try remove the after="-" from the unboxed search layout.

Comment: Good stuff, cheers.

Comment: actually, I was wrong the after didn't change anything but seems you were right and both can work I am little confused yet

Comment: ok my bad i removed the criteo part and was checking and that was why i was seeing the unbxed ones, so it means it is still overwriting and your answer is not right!